# What's a "tourist" sleeper?

Tags: trains, poland, sleeping

I was checking the polish train website and they have in their night offers: "sleeper 1 person", "sleeper 2 persons" and "sleeper touristic".

What does a "sleeper touristic" mean?

Answer (score 5):

While I never used one, I believe those are three-bed sleepers, like the one on this picture:

[image]

Source: Ivor Morgan on [Seat61.com](http://seat61.com/Poland.htm#Krakow)

Traditionally, they could be booked with 2nd class tickets unlike other sleepers, which might explain the different name (rules are more complicated now). See also [Advice for travel by European overnight train in a sleeper or couchette](http://www.seat61.com/sleepers.htm) on seat61.com and [Seat types on European Trains](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/guide-eurail-train-reservations/seat-sleeping-accommodation-types) on Eurail.com.

Comment: They appear on Deutsche Bahn and OEBB's systems as "T3" sleepers, where the others appear as just "2" or "1".